# HTML Select - selected index when opening control

Tags: html, select

I have a dropdown with year values spanning 25 years, 10 years before the current year and 15 years after:

```
<select id="year">
<option value="">Select Year</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
...
<option value="2021">2021</option>
...
<option value="2036">2036</option>
<select>
```

This input is optional.

When the page loads, the control is to show Select Year.

The page that will be used by field users on a smartphone or tablet only.

Our research shows that in around 1 in 3 inputs, user will be required to select a previous year and the rest will be in the future.

I would like it so that when the user taps on the control, the displayed value starts at the current year so user can scroll forwards or backwards through the list rather than having to scroll through previous years if the value to be selected is in the future

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started, but it does have some issues, like as soon as you mouse over the drop down list, the "selected" item changes.

I suppose you'll have to add a `if` clause so it doesn't work at all times.

```js
function setThisYear(selectEle) {
  selectEle.value = "2021";
  selectEle.options[selectEle.selectedIndex].value = 2021;
}
```

```html
<select id="year" onclick="setThisYear(this)">
  <option value="">Select Year</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>

  <option value="2021">2021</option>

  <option value="2031">2031</option>
  <option value="2032">2032</option>
  <option value="2033">2033</option>
  <option value="2034">2034</option>
  <option value="2035">2035</option>
  <option value="2036">2036</option>
</select>
```